# UK Visa for Indian National: Translation Requirements for Employment Contract and Salary Slips

Tags: visas, uk, german-language, translations

I am an Indian national currently working as a research associate in Germany. I want to attend a conference in UK in July, for which I will be applying for a Standard Visitor Visa. I understand that I need to provide a copy of my employment contract and salary statements to support my claim of sufficient finances. However, my employment contract and salary statements are in German. I have the following questions :

1.)Do I need to get these documents translated to English ? If yes, where should I get it done ?

2.) Will it be sufficient, if I do not get the translation done but rather provide  one additional letter from my university (in english) which states that I am employed there and the salary statements and employment contract is valid.

Comment: See ZachLipton's answer below for an accurate reading of your question. Don't forget to use the "Accept Answer" check mark! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) from UK Visas and Immigration for Standard Visitor Visas states:

> If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be
> accompanied by  a full translation that can be independently verified
> by the Home Office.
>
> Each  translated document must contain:
>
> confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of
> the original  document
>
> the date of the translation
>
> the translator's full name and signature
>
> the translator's contact details

That document goes into more detail on the types of documents that are looking for (and the types of documents they don't want to see; if you send these, they'll know you haven't read the guidance). They specifically suggest a letter from your employer, on letterhead, "detailing your role, salary and length of employment." So your idea to provide that would seem to be in line with what they're asking for, instead of having your entire employment contract translated.

As noted in the comments, your bank and other entities may be able to supply documents in English, which would reduce or eliminate the need for translation.

In addition to the guidance linked above, the 'official' rules are at [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)

Comment: you've done nothing, but copy-pasted information from official papers I have provided.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I've copy-pasted the relevant information from the document for the Standard Visitor Visa, which is what the OP is applying for. Your answer indicated a certified translation is required and linked to the guidance for a Tier 4 visa, which is a different process with different requirements. I posted it as a new answer because I thought it rude to completely rewrite yours. This way, people can see both.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk your answer is from the Tier 4 requirements and should be corrected to reflect visitor requirements. I gave you comments that you ignored so ZachLipton made a completely new answer. +1 for this answer, and 0 for yours. Please fix your answer so I can vote on it, or delete it. It is misleading in its current state, thanks

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions ! This makes it much easier.... I can take the letter from my employer with all the required details in english and supplement that with bank statements which the bank can provide in english too...